# Как узнать какой падеж, если несколько глаголов в одной фразе, и какой глагол будет работать

Tags: глаголы

как можно узнать какой падеж если несколько глаголов в одной фразе, и какой глагол будет работать?

например :

> он начинал смотреть интересные кино

какой глагол будет контролировать фразу по падежам, начинать или смотреть, или я буду смотреть, можно смотреть?

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, конкретный пример.

Comment: yes, please detalize your question with examples, as it's not clear

Comment: например : он начинал смотрить .....

Comment: например : он начинал смотреть интересные кино , какой глагол будет контролировать фраза по падежом , начинать или смотрить 
или я буду смотрить , можно смотрить

Comment: control flow there is like `(он -> (начинал -> (смотреть -> кино)))`. The first verb supervises the second verb, and the second verb supervises the noun. You may try to reduce the phrase to bare "он начинал" and then try to restore one of the words and check the meaning. "Он начинал смотреть" vs "он начинал кино" - which is more aligned with the original sentence meaning?

Comment: side note: кино is uncountable and so related adjective should be in singular form.

Answer (score 4):

В составных глагольных формах есть глагол основной /главный,который показывает смысл и вспомогательные, которые дают оттенки, детали этого глагола например

> начал смотреть - смотреть (главное действие), начал – говорит о стадии этого действия.

То же самое в сочетаниях и формах

> можно посмотреть, буду смотреть – смысл выражен инфинитивом **смотреть**, **посмотреть**.

Если дальше идет существительное или местоимение, оно согласуется с **инфинитивом** (смотреть).

> Смотреть что? Фильм.

Первый глагол служит для согласования со словом, которое стоит перед ним, а не после.

> **Я начал, вы начали**.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand which verb is controlling the noun you are curious about.

The control structure of the sentence is typically a tree. From subject via verbs to objects.

For example

> я посмотрел в окно и закрыл книгу.

or

> я закрыл книгу чтобы посмотреть в окно.

Those phrases have two verbs and two nouns each, but they clearly constitute verb-noun pairs: книга is bound to закрыть verb and окно is bound to посмотреть verb.

Then you can look into the dictionary which grammatical cases every of those verbs imposes over their respective bound object nouns.